# How to Create a list from a form using PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm looking to use a form to make updating a list on a website quick and simple. Currently I have standard form that just prints out the contents added onto another page, but what I want is to be able to constantly update the page using the form. For example if I use the form to enter my name as John Smith, it will output John Smith, but If I want to add a friends name later, I want it to add their name to the list:

```
Mike Jones
John Smith
```

Here is the sample form

```
 <html> 
   <head><title>Test Page</title></head> 
   <body> 
     <h2>Data Collection</h2><p> 
     <form action="Test2.php" method="post"> 
     <table> 
       <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="Name" /></td></tr> 
       <tr><td>Age:</td><td><input type="text" name="Age" /></td></tr> 
       <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" /></td></tr> 
     </table> 
     </form> 
    </body> 
 </html>
```

And here is the output.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
    <body>

       <?php 

          print "Your name is ". $Name; 
          print "<br />"; 
          print "You are ". $Age . " years old"; 
          print "<br />"; 

        ?> 
      </body>
    </html>
```

I was thinking that there needs to be some sort of loops/counter that checks to see if new content was added, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: Search for AJAX on the Google.  Plenty of tutorials on how to update pages from form input.

Comment: *"I want it to add their name to the list"* - You either need to use local storage, or save to a file or DB, then retrieve it after.

Comment: If you save it to a file you can append it to the file as: `Name (age) \m` and just reload the page or redo the get content- if you save it to a database <-- which would be better in my opinion, you can make a nice table around it which will be a better sight for the eyes. if you save it to the list you can also do it like append it to the file as `name:age\n`  then split it by then for the output use for example a \n replacement to <br /> and also the : to <br />

Comment: I was really hoping there would a quick simple fix, seeing as all I need is for the new output to be added to the screen without replacing the old. From the sounds of it, I may need to do a little more research.